# What argument format shall be passed to update_post_meta() in order to update a custom field of type PostObject?

Tags: wordpress

Made a script for updating a wp post custom fields. All works fine for the fields with type text or number but a I have issues updating the field of type PostObject that contains a select list.  Can not find any info on the format of the argument that must be passed to the update_post_meta() in order to update the selected value in the WP database of type PostObject.
For now the post id is static just for testing. And do not take into consideration the field name of the $_GET[] const. It is related to a other custom field. It is just given to see structure of the script.

My script test version I use tot change a specific custom field.
[image]

The select where I ge the value from. It returns a string.

[image]

Options of the field I want to change from user input.

[image]

Plugin name:
[image]

Comment: Just a few tips for you to get your problem solved faster: 1- Please take a moment and read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). 2- According to your screenshot you're using `advanced custom field plugin`, so it'd be helpful to include the name of that plugin in your title and in the body of your question. 3- Respectfully, currently, your question is neither clear nor reproducible, so please edit your question and elaborate more and include your real code.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the suggestions. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with the trial and error method :-))).
So, in case you are modifying a custom field of type PostObject, you have to pass as the 'value' argument the ID of the post you want to be the new value of the custom field:
update_post_meta( 15896, 'specialita', '208' );
Thus, in this case the old post ID was for example 325 and and we replace it with a new post with the ID 208.